# VB.NET function with arguments

Tags: vb.net

I have this function in VB.NET:

```
Function RunVoIPCDR(Optional ByVal function_selected_customer As String = "")
    If function_selected_customer > 0 And CallsMonth.SelectedValue <> "" And CallsYear.Text <> "" Then

    End If
End Function
```

but I am getting an error on the If line saying:

> Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: I'm guessing `CallsMonth.SelectedValue` is not a string so `CallsMonth.SelectedValue <> ""` is invalid.  (and/or `function_selected_customer`)  Turn on Option Strict

Comment: One should consider using [AndAlso Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) instead of an `And operator`.

Answer (score 2):

function_selected_customer is a string but you try to use it as if it was a number. If an empty string is considered equal to 0 in your logic you can do somthing like this:

```
 If not string.isNullOrWhitespace(function_selected_customer) andalso function_selected_castomer > 0 and...
```

The `andalso` means that if the first part is false then the other parts will not even be tested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for definate but it looks like this part:
`CallsMonth.SelectedValue <> ""` should be checking for a numeric value rather than an empty string e.g. `CallsMonth.SelectedValue <> 0`

Comment: `function_selected_customer` is FUBAR too

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this

```
function_selected_customer > 0
```

a string cannot be greater than a number. You have to convert the string to a number or have your parameter accept a number.

```
Dim valueAsNumber As Integer

If Not Int32.TryParse(function_selected_customer, valueAsNumber) Then
    valueAsNumber = 0 ' Assuming that you want a 0 for bad input
End If

If valueAsNumber > 0 And ... Then
```

Comment: Int32.Parse will throw an exception when you send it an empty string.

Comment: @ZoharPeled that is true. It's a bit confusing that the default parameter is an empty string but the if statement looks for greater than 0.

Comment: It's seems to me like a rookie's mistake... It's been a while since my vb.net days but I seem to remember Vb.net is very forgiving with implicit convertions... I think if the string will hold a valid integer it will be converted by default, but perhaps I'm wrong.